# JavaFX: Snakes And Ladders - Represent snakes and ladders images in a GridPane

Tags: javafx, gridpane

[image]

I am creating the game Snakes And Ladders. The 10x10 matrix you see is a GridPane where every cell contains a colored Pane.

**PROBLEM**: I want to place images instead of the arrows you see above that represent **the snakes and the ladders**.

> Is spanning multiple columns a solution? Because for example at cell 3
>   to 37 the ladder needs to be a bit rotated.

Edit: Here is my code concerning the GridPane:

```
<GridPane fx:id="gameGrid" alignment="CENTER" hgap="2.0" style="-fx-background-color:#000" vgap="2.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
    <columnConstraints>
        <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        <ColumnConstraints halignment="CENTER" hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    </columnConstraints>
    <rowConstraints>
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    </rowConstraints>
    <children>
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />

        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />

        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />

        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />

        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />

        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />

        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />

        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />

        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="8" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="8" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="8" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="8" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="8" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="8" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="8" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="8" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="8" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="8" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />

        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="9" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="9" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="9" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="9" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="9" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="9" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="9" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="9" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="9" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
        <Pane onMouseClicked="#onCellClick" style="-fx-background-color:#966F33" GridPane.columnIndex="9" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
    </children>
    <BorderPane.margin>
       <Insets bottom="5.0" top="5.0" />
    </BorderPane.margin>
  </GridPane>
```

The FXML design is: http://prntscr.com/k8fpys

Comment: Have you thought about splitting the images up in gimp or photoshop or something and then using the smaller pictures as background images in your grid? That way, at cell 3, the background could be the foot of the ladder and the top of the ladder is in cell 37.

Comment: You could also maybe put your grid pane in a stack pane with a canvas or something behind it containing all the snakes and ladders and any other background colors or images you want. You'd have to somehow make the gridpane background transparent, but that's probably doable.

Comment: As far as your first answer is concerned, the images have transparent background and 549 x 829 size. I have already tried applying the images at the 3rd cell but it's really painful to adjust the exact rotation and the correct layouts X and Y, start X and Y and end X and Y.
Your second answer seems more dealable. Should i place the canvas with the images in the StackPane and beyond the GridPane?

Comment: Yes, the idea is the stackpane would include the canvas and the gridpane. The canvas would have on it the images and the gridpane would have your numbers and/or game pieces.

Comment: Oh I see. So should I remove the panes from the GridPane and just make GridPane's background transparent ?

Comment: If this is the case: Am I going to be able to click on a cell and get the clicked cell's coordinates without a problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure, I don't know exactly what you mean by 'colored panes' here, it's hard for me to help further without seeing any of your code, that's why I've just commented instead of writing a full answer. I just wanted to give you a couple of ideas to explore on your own.

Comment: I will edit the question, give me a min.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution !!!
The hierarchy is:

- I used a **BorderPane** as the base.

  - At the `CENTER` I placed a normal **Pane** *(Panes don't have any    constraints so it's very useful in my case)*.

    1. I used a **GridPane** with each cell containg a **Pane**.
    2. I scaled my images wherever I wanted to and set them to `disabled` and set **`mouseTransparent`** to **true**.

As you see the images are on top of the **GridPane** and I used Panes in each cell of the **GridPane** so I can apply an **`onMouseClick`** handler.